# constexpr in for-Statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, template-meta-programming, if-constexpr

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) provides [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), in which:

> the value of condition must be a contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`. If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded

Is there a way to use this in a `for`-statement as well? To unroll a loop at compile time? Id like to be able to do something like this:

```
template <int T>
void foo() {
   for constexpr (auto i = 0; i < T; ++i) cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: I see no `if constexpr` in your code..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ugh, thanks, I meant to give an example of how I'd like to use a `for constexpr`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758545/unroll-loop-at-compile-time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872919/compile-time-loops

Does the answers of those questions help you, or do you want to use explicitly the for statement for looping?

Comment: No, there is no `for constexpr`. I saw [this discussion over it over on the std-proposals google group](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/A9Swn2Ub2qg), though

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to use this in a for-statement as well? To unroll a loop at compile time? Id like to be able to do something like this

I don't think in a so simple way.

But if you can afford an helper function, with `std::integer_sequence` and the initialization of an unused C-style array of integers, starting from C++14 you can do something as follows

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <int ... Is>
void foo_helper (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> const &)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (std::cout << Is << std::endl, 0)... };
 }

template <int T>
void foo ()
 { foo_helper(std::make_integer_sequence<int, T>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   foo<42>();
 }
```

If you can use C++17, you can avoid the `unused` array and, using folding, `foo_helper()` can be simply written as follows

```
template <int ... Is>
void foo_helper (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> const &)
 { ((std::cout << Is << std::endl), ...); }
```

Comment: Well... I wasn't really looking for a way to improve my toy example, but good gracious, this is fascinating. If you can explain what `unused` is doing here it's worth a +1 from me.

Comment: @JonathanMee - In the meaning I've added a C++17 simplification. Anyway... `unused` is simply a C-style array that is declared only to be initialized with zeros. But using the power of the comma operator, you can add the `std::cout` part **before** the comma so `std::cout` is executed but doesn't affect the values of the array. In other words, `unused` is just a trick to provide an environment where to unpack the `Is...` values.

Answer (score 6):

If loop limits are known to the compiler, compiler will unroll the loop, if it will find it beneficial. Not all loop unrolls are beneficial! And it is unlikely you will make a better decision than compiler as to benefits of loop unrolling.

There is no need for `constexpr for` (as you put it), since `constexpr if` is enabling feature - you may put code which would make program ill-formed inside `constexpr if` false branch - it is not pure optimization.

`Constexpr for`, on the other hand, would be pure optimization (at least as you describe it, not counting the fringe case of loop executed 0 times) and as such is better left to 'as-if' optimization rules.

Comment: "Constexpr for, on the other hand, would be pure optimization" If `constexpr for` existed, the loop variable would be usable in constant expressions such as a template argument lists and consteval functions.

Comment: A `constexpr for` allows you to use the index (or the value) as a constant.  Ie, you can do a constexpr for where the index is used as an array size, or similar.  A classic example of its use is to populate a runtime table with a sequence of different compile time functions whose behavior is computed at compile time for later dispatch; today I'd use a variant of tags for that.  But the case where you need full iteration is also possible.

Answer (score 4):

Not without helper code.

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) noexcept(true) {
  return [](auto&& f)
    RETURNS( decltype(f)(f)( index_t<Is>{}... ) );
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto index_upto( index_t<N> ={} ) noexcept(true) {
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}

template<class F>
constexpr auto foreacher( F&& f ) {
  return [&f](auto&&...args) noexcept( noexcept(f(args))&&... ) {
    ((void)(f(args)),...);
  };
}
```

that is our plumbing.

```
template<int T>
void foo() {
  index_upto<T>()(
    foreacher([](auto I){
      std::cout << I << "\n";
    })
  );
}
```

a compile time loop with values on each step.

Or we can hide the details:

```
template<std::size_t start, std::size_t length, std::size_t step=1, class F>
constexpr void for_each( F&& f, index_t<start> ={}, index_t<length> ={}, index_t<step> ={} ) {
  index_upto<length/step>()(
    foreacher([&](auto I){
      f( index_t<(I*step)+start>{} );
    })
  );
}
```

then we'd get:

```
for_each<0, T>([](auto I) {
  std::cout << I << "\n";
});
```

or

```
for_each([](auto I) {
  std::cout << I << "\n";
}, index_t<0>{}, index_t<T>{});
```

this can be further improved with user defined literals and template variables:

```
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

template<char...cs>
constexpr auto operator""_idx() {
  return index< parse_value(cs...) >;
}
```

where `parse_value` is a `constexpr` function that takes a sequence of `char...` and produces an unsigned integer representation of it.

Comment: `decltype(f)(f)` – I think I’ve seen this somewhere else too; could you explain the purpose of that?

Comment: @Socob It is a pseudo-std-forward.  I read it as `f` as the type it was declared as.  It only works for `auto&&` type variables; otherwise, it can induce a copy.  It is equivalent in that case to `std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)`.