# template lambda vs functor with template operator()

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic-templates, c++20

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648387/c-generic-compile-time-for-loop), I would like to compare the use of `c++20` template lambda with a functor having a template `operator()`.

As a test case, consider a template function `call` which takes a template lambda as an argument, and call this lambda instantiating it with some template parameters. The following `c++20` code exemplifies the idea.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <int I, class Lambda, class... ArgsType>
void call(Lambda&& F, ArgsType&& ...args)
{
           F.template operator()<I>(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);
}

int main() {
   std::tuple<int, double, int> t{0,0,0};
   int a = 2;

   auto f = [&]<int I>(auto& x) { std::get<I>(x) += I + a; };
   call<0>(f, t);

   return 0;
}
```

In `c++11`/`c++14`/`c++17`, not having template lambda, the same task can be implemented with a functor, having a template `operator()`, as in the following code.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <int I, class Lambda, class... ArgsType>
void call(Lambda&& F, ArgsType&& ...args)
{
           F.template operator()<I>(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...);
}

struct Functor {
    template <int I, class T>
    void operator()(const int& a, T& x) { std::get<I>(x) += I + a; };
};

int main() {
   std::tuple<int, double, int> t{0,0,0};
   int a = 2;

   Functor func{};
   call<0>(func, a, t);

}
```

The main disadvantage I see in the second example is that, to emulate the lambda capture, one needs to pass explicitly all local variables (in this case `int a`) to the functor. This can be tedious, if `Functor::operator()` needs many variables from its "owner". Eventually, one could also perhaps pass the pointer `this` to `Functor::operator()`.
No such complications are present in the `c++20` example, where the lambda capture takes care of capturing the needed variables.

Aside from simplicity, is there any other concrete difference between the two approaches outlined above? What about the efficiency?

Comment: That's essentially the same comparison as between plain functors and generic lambdas, or (fully-deducible) templated functors and generic lambdas.

Comment: @Quentin The comparison is perhaps similar, but for example, you cannot define a local class with member templates, so you need, as in the second code, to declare the functor outside main, whereas the c++20 lambda of the first code is local.

Comment: seems like you answer your own question. There is nothing wrong with that btw, but better put the answer in an answer instead of the question and comments...

Comment: C++14 already has generic lambdas which can be called with explicit template arguments (with the ugly `operator()<>` syntax).  C++20 merely allows explicit template **parameter** lists for them (as is particularly helpful with concepts).

Comment: @DavisHerring but how would it work with non-type template parameters?

Comment: @francesco: There can’t be an actual non-type parameter, since `auto` can’t produce one (although it could be `X<1>` from which the 1 might be extracted).  I was simply responding to “In `c++11`/`c++14`/`c++17`, not having template lambda” since it seemed to imply that `F.template operator()<…>` is C++20-specific.

Answer (score 2):

> The main disadvantage I see in the second example is that, to emulate the lambda capture, one needs to pass explicitly all local variables (in this case int a) to the functor.

I disagree.

You can see a lambda almost as a class/struct with an `operator()` and some member corresponding to the captured variables.

So instead of

```
[&]<int I>(auto& x) { std::get<I>(x) += I + a; };
```

you can write (already from C++11)

```
struct nal // not a lambda
 {
   int const & a;

   template <int I, typename T>
   auto operator() (T & x) const
    { std::get<I>(x) += I + a; }
 };
```

and use it as follows

```
call<0>(nal{a}, t);
```

The main disadvantage I see with functors (and I suppose it's questionable that is a disadvantage) is that you can't simply capture, by reference or by value (`[&]` or `[=]`), all external variables but you have to explicitly list all the variable you use, both in defining the functor and in initializing the functor object.

Off Topic: observe that I've tagged `const` the `operator()` in my `nal` structure.

If you don't modify the captured variables, the lambdas are equivalent to functors with constant `operator()`.

This is important if you pass the functor as constant reference

```
template <int I, class Lambda, class... ArgsType>
void call (Lambda const & F, ArgsType&& ...args)
{ // ......^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  now F is a constant reference
  F.template operator()<I>(std::forward<ArgsType>(args)...); // compilation error
                                                             // if operator()
                                                             // isn't const
}
```

you get a compilation error if `operator()` isn't `const`

Comment: On writing *The main disadvantage I see with functors...* I mean that you need to pass all the relevant variables to the functor, whatever the way you do that (constructor in your answer, or parameters to ```operator()``` in my code). If you change the code of the functor, and need more variables, you have to also change the declaration and/or the constructor. With capture [&] you get all of them automatically.

Comment: @francesco - OK: we are agree about this; what I want to say is that you don't need to pass the captured variables as arguments of the `operator()`.

Comment: By creating a reference inside the ```struct nal```, I think you have an extra overhead as compared to the lambda.

Comment: @francesco - I don't think there is a great overhead in a constant reference; anyway (1) as far I know, is exactly what happens with a lambda capturing by reference (except that with lambda all is done implicitly) and (2) also in you example (where you pass `a` as argument for `operator()`) you use a constant reference.

Comment: Yes, also passing ```a``` to ```operator()``` you use a reference, but the compiler *should* be able to optimize it out, while this is maybe more difficult if you create a reference in ```nal``` that persists after ```operator()``` has exited.

Comment: @francesco - I'm not a expert of compilers so I don't know which case is best optimized; anyway, a lambda capturing by reference has to create reference variable inside it; I don't see difference, in this case.

Comment: (The type of) a lambda expression **is** a class with an `operator()` and member variables per capture.