# Repeatedly calling a function with a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function with a non-type template parameter of type `int`, like so:

```cpp
template <int N>
int foo() { /*...*/ }
```

I would like to unit test this function for all values of `N` from 0 to 32. I have a function `int expected(int n)` that takes the same `N` value and returns the expected value. Effectively, I want:

```cpp
if (foo<0>() != expected(0)) { /* fail... */ }
if (foo<1>() != expected(1)) { /* fail... */ }
if (foo<2>() != expected(2)) { /* fail... */ }
// 30 more lines
```

I don't want to write out all 33 test cases by hand, and I can't easily use a runtime loop because `N` is compile time.

How can I get the compiler to generate the test cases for me in a simple way, without `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`-style tricks or code generation, in C++11?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to continue or abort if a test fails?

Comment: I am using Catch2 and the test looks like `REQUIRE(foo<0>() == expected(0))` which aborts using some Catch2-specific magic, and depending on command line flags. I didn't really want to introduce the complication of the Catch2 macro here though. Does it answer your question @M.M?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ generic compile-time for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648387/c-generic-compile-time-for-loop)

Answer (score 5):

You can write a recursive function template with [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) to perform the test. e.g.

```
template <int N>
void test() {
    test<N-1>();
    if (foo<N>() != expected(N)) { /* fail... */ }
}

template <>
void test<-1>() {
    // do nothing
}
```

and run it like

```
test<32>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In c++14 you can do something like this

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int beg, int end> struct static_for {
    template <typename Fn> void operator()(Fn const& fn) const {
        if (beg < end) {
            fn(std::integral_constant<int, beg>());
            static_for<beg + 1, end>()(fn);
        }
    }
};

template <int n> struct static_for<n, n> {
    template <typename Fn> void operator()(Fn const& fn) const {}
};

template <int N> int foo() { /*...*/
    return N;
}

int main() {
    static_for<0, 32>()([&](auto i) {
        if (foo<i>() != i) { /* fail... */
        }
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method:

```cpp
template<int N>
void f();

template<int... N>
void g(std::index_sequence<N...>)
{
  (f<N>(), ...);
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
g(std::make_index_sequence<33>());
```

## Edit:

Here's version that actually checks if the tests completed successfully:

```cpp
template<int N>
int f();

int expected(int n);

template<int... N>
bool g(std::index_sequence<N...>)
{
  return ((f<N>() == expected(N)) && ...);
}
```

Which is used like:

```cpp
g(std::make_index_sequence<33>()); // true if all tests are sucessful, false otherwise
```

Comment: The `(f<N>(), ...);` part doesn't compile under C++11 or C++14, at least for me. Does it require C++17?

Comment: To match the template parameter, you could replace `index_sequence` with `integer_sequence<int,...>`.

Comment: Not really significant but... the OP ask for a sequence "from 0 to 32"; so the template argument for `std::make_index_sequence` should be `33`, not `31` (if I'm not wrong)

Comment: @BeeOnRope - yes: template folding is available starting from C++17.

Answer (score 0):

A possible C++14 solution, that "simulate" the C++17 template-folding and interrupt the `f<N> != expected(N)` at first failure

```
template <int N>
void f ();

template <int ... Is>
void g (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   bool ret { false };

   (void)unused { 0, (ret ? 0 : (ret = (f<Is>() != expected(Is)), 0))... }; 
 }
```

callable as follows

```
g(std::make_integer_sequence<33>());
```

For a C++11 solution, you need a substitute for `std::make_integer_sequence`/`std::integer_sequence` that are available only from C++14.