# Printing Pairs inside tuple in C++

Tags: c++, tuples, std-pair, stdtuple

I am trying to print all the values of pair inside of a tuple,

**header file**

```
template <typename... Args>
void printPairs(std::tuple<Args...> t)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)  //the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression
    {
        auto pair = std::get<i>(t);
        cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << endl;
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
std::tuple<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>> t1 = {std::make_pair(1, 2), std::make_pair(3, 4), std::make_pair(5, 6), std::make_pair(7, 8)};
printPairs(t1);
```

If you would not iterate and put a constant value instead of "i", works fine

```
auto pair = std::get<1>(t);
 cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << endl;
```

Comment: The `for` loop is something which is executed at run-time but you try to resolve compile-time indexes with `std::get<>`. You would need something like `for constexpr` (which doesn't exist AFAIK). You could try to use recursion or fold expressions...

Comment: FYI: [SO: compile time loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872919/compile-time-loops) (It's a bit aged.) [SO: c++ generic compile-time for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55648387/7478597), or just [google "c++ compile time iteration"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+compile+time+iteration) by yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
template<typename Tuple>
void printPairs(const Tuple& t) {
  std::apply([](const auto&... pair) {
    ((std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << std::endl), ...);
  }, t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename... Args, size_t... Is>
void printPairsHelper(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    ((std::cout << std::get<Is>(t).first << " "
                << std::get<Is>(t).second << std::endl), ...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void printPairs(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    printPairsHelper(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oes59xczG)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to print elements of a tuple in a loop because, as it was already explained in one of the comments, loops (for, while etc.) are evaluated at run-time and to iterate over tuple you'd need something that works at compile-time.

One solution that I see would be to first write a little utility function(s):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t... Ints, typename... Args, typename Proc>
void forEachImpl(std::tuple<Args...> const& tuple, Proc&& proc, std::index_sequence<Ints...>) {
    (..., proc(std::get<Ints>(tuple)));
}

template<typename... Args, typename Proc>
void forEach(std::tuple<Args...> const& tuple, Proc&& proc) {
    forEachImpl(tuple, proc, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
}
```

The one which we're going to use is `forEach` (`forEachImpl` is just an implementation helper function used by `forEach`). What it does is, it calls `proc` with each element of tuple as an argument.

Then we can go back to your function - `printPairs` - and the main function:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void printPairs(std::tuple<Args...> const& tuple) {
    forEach(tuple, [] (auto const& pair) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ' ' << pair.second << '\n';
    });
}

int main() {
    std::tuple t(std::pair(1, 3), std::pair('x', 'y'), std::pair(-5.3f, 3.7L));
    printPairs(t);
}
```