# Repeat Code in C Based on Compile time Arguments

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have a some C code, say, `printf("A");` how can I repeat it N number of times based on some compile time argument where N is passed in that compiler argument. e.g `gcc -D print=N`

Similarly, is there a way where we can pass the range of the loop based on the compile time argument/flag?

Comment: Can you please clarify.

Comment: The second is easy `for (int i = 0; i < print; ++i) ...` The first could be done in C++ with templates, not sure about C though.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872919/compile-time-loops

Comment: Please see [How to pass macro definition from “make” command line arguments (-D) to C source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/how-to-pass-macro-definition-from-make-command-line-arguments-d-to-c-source)

Comment: C and C++ are different languages and need different answers for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put it into a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < print; ++i)
  printf("A");
```

The `print` symbol will be substituted by the value specified on the compiler command line (e.g. `-Dprint=5`), so the loop runs the desired amount of times. You can do the same thing with the start value `0` by adding another `-D` definition to use a different range.

However, `print` is not a good name for such a macro; it's convention to use a longer name in all caps to avoid collisions with e.g. function names.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I repeat it N number of times based on some compile time argument where N is passed in that compiler argument

Just *generate* a C file, perhaps using another script (or [metaprogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), that you could write in [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), C++ or even  C) to generate it. Configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)) accordingly.

Remember, you can  `#include` a *generated* file.

For examples (of C file generators), see [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/).

See also [this blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) (from the late Jacques Pitrat).

You could also be interested in [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).